# How to append a jQuery DOM object to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have

```
<div id='foo'></div>
```

why does `$("#foo").append($("bar"));` not do anything? And how can I make it work?

Comment: Could it be because you don't have a `<bar></bar>` element ?

Comment: For consideration: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Missing ID selector..?

Comment: @adeneo My bad. I horribly misinterpreted jQuery's API and thought that `$('bar')` made an empty text element with 'bar'.

Comment: That would be `$('<div />', {text: 'bar'})`, note the brackets.

Comment: If you mean text *node*, just do `$("#foo").append("bar");`. There is no such thing as a text *element*.

Comment: ^^^ Then there's that +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what is $("bar")? as it is in the example you posted its nothing. so you are adding nothing to your div. If you want to add a new div with an id of bar you could do something like this:

```
$("#foo").append("<div id=\"bar\"></div>");
```

there are some other options too but this one is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably trying to do `$("#foo").append("bar");` or `$("#foo").append($("#bar"));`

Should work if you have a bar element though